# Adding an EKAlarm to EKReminder with a recurrence rule

Tags: ios, xcode, eventkit

I have a quick question for someone familiar with Event Kit...

I'm creating recurring reminders and I'd like an alarm to sound at each recurrence. However, the documentation suggests I can only create an alarm with an absolute date or a relative offset. Is there any way to get an alarm to fire every time the reminder reoccurs? Does it do this automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since `EKReminder` is a subclass of `EKCalendarItem` you can use the `addRecurrenceRule:` method to add a recurrence rule so the reminder repeats. Unfortunately, you can't create a recurring alarm since the relative offset alarm is based on the start date of the reminder, and not the date of each recurring reminder. However, you can add multiple `EKAlarm`'s to your `EKReminder` object so if your event repeats a discrete number of times, you could add an alarm for each. If it repeats forever, you may be out of luck since Apple's docs say:

> Be warned that some calendars can only allow a certain maximum number
>   of alarms. When this item is saved, it will truncate any extra alarms
>   from the array.